# Return to activity without creating a new instance

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have a SplashScreenActivity which will run every 2 minutes if there is no touch detected on the MainActivity. If the 'Start' button is pressed on the SplashScreenActivity, it starts MainActivity.

My problem is when the 'Start' button is pressed on the SplashScreenActivity, a new instance of MainActivity is created each time, thus loading up my libraries and initialization each time (in OnCreate()). This significantly slows down my application and lags when the button is pressed. I only want this to run **once** when the application is first started.

I have tried using

```
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {       
            /*
             * Showing splash screen with a timer. This will be useful when you
             * want to show case your app logo / company
             */

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // This method will be executed once the timer is over
                // Start your app main activity
                Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);   
                startActivity(i);

                // close this activity
                finish();
            }
    }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);
```

...when the Intent has started, but my libraries and initialization in OnCreate() in MainActivity are still being run again.

When 'Start' button pressed in SplashScreenActivity, runs the following method:

```
    public void startIntent(View v){
         Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
         i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);   
         startActivity(i);
     }
```

Any help?

---

Currently have the lines (taken out setFlags):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Email.this, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

And still MainActivity's OnCreate() is being called each time the activity has started.

---

So I've found out that if I set the following:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
```

I can successfully return to my MainActivity without it creating a new instance.

Click [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT) for more info.

Comment: more code please, can we see the onClickListener for Button and your MainActivity. Thanks

Comment: Now that you've got it solved, you should write up the solution as an answer and accept it. That will help future searchers, and will mark this question as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to show a **SplashScreen (meaning a picture)**, 
then you should consider to make an **ImageView within any layout** on the same level as the main layout.

Then you can make the **ImageView/SplashScreen visible or invisble** in your code.

This way you may save a lot of work.

Answer (score 1):

[`Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) clears everything on top of the target activity in the stack. In your case, when you call the SplashScreen, you're telling the MainActivity to close itself.

Comment: Ahh... I see. Do you know how to just 'switch' to another Activity without closing the current one?

Comment: Just don't set that flag. get rid of the `setFlags()` line. You may want to keep it when transitioning from the splash to the main activity. Just not the other way around.

Comment: Thanks @Geobits. I've taken out the setFlags line - still seems to create a new instance of MainActivity each time and runs OnCreate() again. Actually, OnCreate() in MainActivity is being run **twice**.